# Can I store yaml files for Github actions in different directory to .github/workflows

Tags: github-actions

I need to put the files in a src folder, is that possible, will Github actions be able to see the files.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What is your use case?

Comment: According to https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/about-workflows#about-workflows and https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/understanding-github-actions#workflows, "**Workflows are defined in the .`github/workflows` directory in a repository**".

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do this. It’s completely locked to that folder.

Only for action.yml files this is allowed (can be put anywhere, but then you do have to reference them differently with the full folder path).